# Как взять класс элемента которого создал не html a js

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Мне нужно взять класс элемента который создал JS уже все перепробовал ничего не работает и `className` и `setattribute`

```
let variants = [1, 2];
let start = document.getElementById("Start");
let br = document.createElement("br")
let i;

function StartGame() {
  start.hidden = true;
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    let butt = document.createElement("button");
    butt.classList.add("butt")
    butt.innerHTML = "0";
    document.body.append(butt);

  };
};
/*if(i === 15){
    i = 0;
document.body.append(br);
};
*/
function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand);
}
let butts = document.querySelectorAll(".butt");
butts.onclick = function() {
  alert(randomInteger(1, 3));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let variants = [1, 2];
let start = document.getElementById("Start");
let br = document.createElement("br")
let i;

function StartGame() {
  //start.hidden = true;
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    let butt = document.createElement("button");
    butt.classList.add("butt")
    butt.innerHTML = "0";
    document.body.append(butt);
  };
  
  document.querySelectorAll('.butt').forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
          alert(randomInteger(1, 3));
      });
  });
};

function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand);
}

StartGame();
```

```css
.butt {
  border: qpx solid blue;
}
```

---

```js
let variants = [1, 2];
let start = document.getElementById("Start");
let br = document.createElement("br")
let i;

function StartGame() {
  //start.hidden = true;
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    let butt = document.createElement("button");
    butt.classList.add("butt")
    butt.innerHTML = "0";
    document.body.append(butt);
  };
};

function randomInteger(min, max) {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand);
}

// Через делегирование
document.addEventListener('click', event => { 
    if (event.target.className === 'butt') {
        alert(randomInteger(1, 3));
    }
});

StartGame();
```

```css
.butt {
  border: qpx solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Алексей Шиманский вопрос а зачем его перебирать с помощью функции?

Comment: @Half кого "его"?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.butt').forEach((el) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {
          alert(randomInteger(1, 3));
      });

Comment: потому что слушателя надо навесить на **каждый** элемент, иначе он будет навешан только на первый